# Getting error while running magento deploy command

Tags: magento2

I am installing magento2 claue theme, while running deploy command I am getting below error

[image]

After following all the steps final theme looks like below which is not proper.

[image]

Please help me to resolve this issue ASAP. I am using magento version 2.3.4.

Comment: Have you tried deploy after clearing var/view_preprocessed and pub/static/frontend/Mgs/Claue_rtl directory. 

`rm -rf pub/static/frontend/Mgs/Claue_rtl; rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*;`

Comment: Thank you for the solution. But it didn't help. Still issue persist.